# SQL query issue: display all staff names with counts from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables, `Job_support` and `Job_interaction`, both containing data related to various staff members. I'm trying to create a query that generates a report with the total counts for each staff member from both tables. I want to ensure that all staff names are included in the result, even if there are no corresponding records in one of the tables.

Here are the sample tables:

**Table 1 - Job_support:**

```
CNT     Staff
1       Tom Smith
2       N/A
```

**Table 2 - Job_interaction:**

```
Staff       CNT
Tom Smith   1
Alice Adams 2
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
Staff         Job_support_cnt   Job_interaction_cnt
Tom Smith     1                 1
Alice Adams   0                 2
Amber         0                 0
Unassigned    2                 N/A
```

I've attempted to use the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    Job_interaction.staff,
    Job_interaction.cnt AS Job_interaction_cnt,
    Job_support_cnt.cnt AS Job_support_cnt
FROM
    Job_interaction
JOIN
    Job_support ON Job_support.staff = Job_interaction.staff;
```

However, the output only includes staff members with matching records in both tables, like this:

```
Staff         Job_support_cnt   Job_interaction_cnt
Tom Smith     1                 1
```

How can I modify my query to ensure that all staff names(ones that do not have the counts in the first two tables also like Amber) are displayed in the first column, and the corresponding counts are populated from both tables, with zeros or "N/A" for missing values? Is there a specific function or join I should be using to achieve this result?

---

I also tried the below query -

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(Job_interaction.staff, Job_support.staff, 'Unassigned') AS Staff,
    COALESCE(Job_support.cnt, 0) AS Job_support_cnt,
    COALESCE(Job_interaction.cnt, 0) AS Job_interaction_cnt
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT staff FROM Job_support
     UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT staff FROM Job_interaction) StaffList
LEFT JOIN Job_support ON StaffList.staff = Job_support.staff
LEFT JOIN Job_interaction ON StaffList.staff = Job_interaction.staff
```

Comment: Looking at sample data & expected result could you tell where did Amber come from??? Or tell us the logic behind value 3 in last resulting column for Tom Smith??? Or....

Comment: "amber" , tom and alice are 3 staff members that may have data, right now the table doesnt have valeu for amber but it may in the future, so the first column actually has to be hard coded

Comment: @dr-the 3 value was a typo, i fixed it, Kindly suggest how to hard code the first column and then give the corresponding values in the right. With the final query i wrote, the hard coding of the first column wont work

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Edit your first question to address the comments and leave your own comment asking for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very bad to hard code things like that, I suppose that you have somewhere a table where staff is listed. If don't then consider the first cte (staff) in code below as hard coding staff names:

```sql
WITH      --  S am p l e   D a t a :
    staff  (ID, A_NAME) AS
        ( Select 1, 'Tom Smith'     From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 'Alice Adams' From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, 'Amber'           From Dual Union All 
          Select 4, 'Unassigned'    From Dual 
        ),
    job_support (CNT, STAFF) AS
        ( Select 1, 'Tom Smith' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 'N/A'         From Dual 
        ), 
    job_interaction (STAFF, CNT) AS
        ( Select 'Tom Smith', 1     From Dual Union All 
          Select 'Alice Adams', 2 From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select      stf.ID, stf.A_NAME "STAFF", 
          Sum(Nvl(supp.CNT, 0)) "JOB_SUPPORT_CNT",
          Sum(Nvl(jint.CNT, 0)) "JOB_INTERACTION_CNT"
From            staff stf
Left Join   job_support supp ON(Replace(supp.STAFF, 'N/A', 'Unassigned') = stf.A_NAME)
Left Join   job_interaction jint ON(Replace(jint.STAFF, 'N/A', 'Unassigned') = stf.A_NAME)
Group By    stf.ID, stf.A_NAME
Order By    stf.ID
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID STAFF       JOB_SUPPORT_CNT JOB_INTERACTION_CNT
---------- ----------- --------------- -------------------
         1 Tom Smith                 1                   1
         2 Alice Adams               0                   2
         3 Amber                     0                   0
         4 Unassigned                2                   0    */
```

NOTE: Here I kept the cnt columns as numbers, if you want to have 'N/A' then the cnt columns should be converted to VARCHAR2 and the 'N/A' should be handled separately.
Something like below:

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select      stf.ID, stf.A_NAME "STAFF",
          Case When stf.A_NAME = 'Unassigned' Then 'N/A'
          Else To_Char(Sum(Nvl(supp.CNT, 0))) End  "JOB_SUPPORT_CNT",
          Case When stf.A_NAME = 'Unassigned' Then 'N/A'
          Else To_Char(Sum(Nvl(jint.CNT, 0))) End "JOB_INTERACTION_CNT"
From            staff stf
Left Join   job_support supp ON(Replace(supp.STAFF, 'N/A', 'Unassigned') = stf.A_NAME)
Left Join   job_interaction jint ON(Replace(jint.STAFF, 'N/A', 'Unassigned') = stf.A_NAME)
Group By    stf.ID, stf.A_NAME
Order By    stf.ID
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID STAFF       JOB_SUPPORT_CNT   JOB_INTERACTION_CNT     
---------- ----------- ----------------- ------------------------
         1 Tom Smith   1                 1                       
         2 Alice Adams 0                 2                       
         3 Amber       0                 0                       
         4 Unassigned  N/A               N/A                      */
```

Answer (score 0):

Something based on :

```
SELECT
    Job_interaction.staff,
    COALESCE(Job_interaction.cnt, 0) AS Job_interaction_cnt,
    COALESCE(Job_support_cnt.cnt, 0) AS Job_support_cnt
FROM
    Job_interaction
FULL OUTER JOIN
    Job_support ON Job_support.staff = Job_interaction.staff;
```

Please post DDL of your table

With your new comments, the final query is quite simple based on the previous :

```
-- BEGIN SAMPLE DATA :
WITH 
    staff  (ID, A_NAME) AS
        ( Select 1, 'Tom Smith'     Union All 
          Select 2, 'Alice Adams' Union All 
          Select 3, 'Amber'           
        ),
    job_support (CNT, STAFF) AS
        ( Select 1, 'Tom Smith' Union All 
          Select 2, 'N/A'        
        ), 
    job_interaction (STAFF, CNT) AS
        ( Select 'Tom Smith', 1     Union All 
          Select 'Alice Adams', 2  
        )
-- END SAMPLE DATA
-- THE FINAL QUERY
SELECT COALESCE(staff.A_NAME, 'Unassigned') AS name,
       COALESCE(job_interaction.CNT, 0) AS Job_interaction_cnt,
       COALESCE(job_support.CNT, 0) AS Job_support_cnt
FROM   staff
       FULL OUTER JOIN  job_interaction ON staff.A_NAME = job_interaction.STAFF
       FULL OUTER JOIN  job_support ON staff.A_NAME  = job_support.STAFF;
```

NOTE : Recent version of ORACLE does not need any more dual table...

Comment: @SQLpro- This query will work but I want the first column to have all th staff members like Tom, alice and amber and the corresponding counts on the next two columns. If amber is not in the table then the cnt should be 0

Comment: so it should match the name and then display the count

Comment: Where did come "Amber" ? SQL is not magic... The table you provide does not have any Amber !

Comment: hi @sqlpro, there are only 3 possible staff member names. currently no support or interaction is created for amber which is why the first two tables do not have value for that. The first column will always be fixed ... and can have value "TOM" , ALIC AND AMBER ONLY these three should always be displayed even if the table 1 and table 2 have no data for these. I understand sql is not magic, hence the staff column should be hard coded and matched with the staff column from table 1 and table 2, if there is a match then the count should come up, if not 0 should be displayed